# ActiveAdmin alternative for Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, activeadmin, rack

What are good admin interface options in `Sinatra`? Rails has `activeadmin`, can I use `activeadmin` with Sinatra?

Comment: Per the close reasons, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at http://www.padrinorb.com/ . Looks like it comes with a built in admin interface and is built specifically for Sinatra.

Comment: I'll have to rewrite my project in Padrino? Or I can use padrino's admin in my Sinatra App?

Comment: I've not personally used it before, but it looks like you just do the following:

```gem install padrino```

```padrino g project myapp -d datamapper -b```

```cd myapp```

```padrino g admin```

```padrino rake dm:migrate seed```

```padrino start```